# Unable to clear cache of WebBrowser control in windows phone 8

Tags: caching, windows-phone-8, cookies, webbrowser-control

I have used a WebBrowser control in my windows phone application. Using webbrowser control i am logging into my application. On log-out i simply redirect the user to log-in page again and trying to clear the cache and cookies of the webbrowser control.

```
mybrowser.ClearCookiesAsync();
mybrowser.ClearInternetCacheAsync();
```

instead of showing log-in screen, it get the previous credentials and logged-in into the application. Can anyone please help me in clearing the cookies and cache of webbrowser conteol.
Complete code:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
            App.AccessToken = "";
            myBrowser.Navigate(new Uri(login URL));

        }
        void Navigating(object sender, NavigatingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Login complete)
            {
                clearCahe();
            }
        }
public async void clearCahe()
        {
            await myBrowser.ClearCookiesAsync();
            await mybrowser.ClearInternetCacheAsync();
        }
```

Comment: are you `awaiting` those calls?

Comment: @ChubosaurusSoftware: yes i am awaiting them. even i have tried this one as well:var cookies = myBrowser.GetCookies();
                foreach (Cookie item in cookies)
                {
                    if (item.Domain.Contains("microsoft.com"))
                    {
                        item.Discard = true;
                        item.Expired = true;
                    }
                }

Comment: Well if those two methods don't out for you then your best bet is dispose that `WebBrowser` control and create a new one in its place.

Comment: i have tried that method method as well, onnavigating from page i am removing the webbrowser control and on navigated to that page i am creating new webbrowser control and adding them to contentpanel.

Comment: hmm, k I think you're awaiting them incorrectly.  I just did a sample app logged on to google and clearing and it works just fine.  Can you post the code how you're doing it please?

Comment: i have updated the code, please have a look

Comment: K, I see what is wrong wait up.

Answer (score 0):

`async functions` are hard to get use to.  If you put a break point at

```
await myBrowser.ClearCookiesAsync();  // put a break point here then step-in (F11 on the keyboard)
```

You will see that will not actually await and will continue on its merry way.

To fix this you have to do something like this

```C#
using System.Threading.Task;

public async Task<bool> clearCahe()
{
    await myBrowser.ClearCookiesAsync();
    await mybrowser.ClearInternetCacheAsync();
    return true;
}
```

and a calling function that also async

like so

```C#
private async void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await clearCache();
    // then navigate the page
}
```

Comment: @KdSingh well let me know what happens, it works for me.

Comment: sorry man, this approach is also not working foe me, i am clearing cache onload and onnavigatedfrom event.

Comment: @KdSingh hmm, try creating a new project and add in the basic code to navigate to google.com sign in, then run the async code above, you will see next time you goto the website it is cleared, if you don't clear it will have your login at the top right.

Comment: ohk sure i will try this one

Comment: i have tried this approach in console application, this approach is working for google account, but unfortunately it is not working for my applications.

Comment: i have tried same thing for Microsoft account, but is also not working for Microsoft accounts, can you please try your console application for any microsoft account.

Comment: did you try for any live account ? please help me out to get out from this situation.

Comment: @KdSingh yes, I tried with Hotmail.com.  It worked just fine, I had to add `myBrowser.IsScriptEnabled = true;` for it to let me login though, click on `remember me` and sure enough it remember me until I call the clearCache() function.